# XML multi records Talend

Tags: xml, talend

I have a file XML that contains many records and I want to create a flow for every element, and then generate a file XML that has the same structure as the file input. I have tried to do this :

tFileinputXML -> tMAP -> tAdvancedFileOutputXML for every elements but it didn't work.

The file input XML is like this :

```
<R>   
   <A>
    <A1>1</A1>
    <A2>premier</A2>
   </A>
   <A>
    <A1>2</A1>
    <A2>second</A2>
   </A>
</R>
```

Thanks

Comment: Just for clarification: Do you want to generate one file per record (i.e. split the input file into per-record output files)? Or what is the flow supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure XML in metadata

"Absolute XPath expression" : "/R/A" means this is loop element

Please add the fields (A1,A2) which need to be extracted in "Fields to Extract" section

Manas
http://www.talendfreelancer.com/